# Android developement with Delphi on One Plus X: how to?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, oneplusx

I own Delphi 10 Seattle and I am struggling to setup my IDE for Android development.

My phone is One Plus X.

I went through the docs at embarcadero website, in particular [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Configuring_Your_System_to_Detect_Your_Android_Device)

I did all up to point (6), but point (7) is not ok: I do not see my device.

I tried to go through all the points several time, I also made sure to run explorer with elevated privileges to be sure that everything is installed fine. Anyway as I choose Android as target platform there is no way to see my phone in the "Target" folder.

Did anyone manage to use One Plus X (and its drivers) for Android Development on Delphi Seattle?

I used this [driver](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979) as USB driver for one plus X, having no errors on installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrying for the nth time i manager do see my phone.

Success come after following step by step [this guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Installing_the_USB_Driver_for_Your_Android_Device):

> 1. Start the **Android SDK Manager** by selecting **Start | All Programs | Embarcadero RAD Studio | Android SDKs | Android Tools**
>
>    > **Caution:** Use only the Android SDK Manager that is available in the **Android Tools** node on the **Start** menu. 
>    >     Do not use any other Android SDK Manager that might be installed elsewhere on your system.
>    >     A command window opens, and then the **Android SDK Manager** opens.
> 2. In the Android SDK Manager:
>
>    1. Scroll down to **Extras**.
>    2. Select the **Google USB Driver**.
>    3. Clear all other checkmarks, such as automatic checkmarks in the **Android 4.3** and **Tools** sections.
>
>       > **Note:** We recommend that you do not install additional libraries or updates except as distributed by RAD Studio.
>    4. Click **Install 1 Package**.
> 3. Power up your Android device and connect it by USB cable to your development system.
> 4. In the system **Control Panel**, search for and select "update device drivers" in order to open the **Device Manager**.
> 5. In the **Device Manager**, locate and right-click your Android device, and select **Update Driver Software**.
> 6. In the **Update driver software** dialog box, browse to the **\extras** folder in your Android SDK directory, and select the folder that matches your Android device. (For example, select **google** for the Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 tablet.) Then click **OK**.
>
>    > **Note:** This is the location of the Google USB driver in our default Android SDK installation: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-<Version>\extras\google\usb_driver`.

OnePlus added to the list:

[image]